# CSS multiple divs overflow

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I have a sample with 10 divs in a row, places in one container, in the footer of the site. This site will be a responsive one, it will work on smartphones too.

On smartphones, I want to make a horizontal scrollview, but I need the overflown divs (for example, 4,5,6,7,8,9,10) to be placed in a row, outside the viewport (I will slide them in). With the css from [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hkFPB/), the divs that don't have place in the row are placed under the viewport, not in the same row. **How can I place them in the same row?**

Basically, I want just n squares in the viewport, the rest of them, I will slide them in.

P.S. I'm trying to do this manually, are there some scroll viewer plugins in jQuery? (not jQuery Mobile)

Comment: I think you might need another wrapping div. Most sliders I've seen will have a div with `overflow: hidden` and inside that is a really wide div (at least wide enough to hold all the content) that gets moved. As for plugins, I've used [jQuery Tools](http://jquerytools.org/) a few times

Comment: @MrOBrian Please put your comment as an answer, to let me marked it as the right answer. It was very helpful, thank you.

Comment: Oh cool. I wasn't sure if it was what you were looking for, but I'm glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need another wrapping div. Most sliders I've seen will have a div with `overflow: hidden` and inside that is a really wide div (at least wide enough to hold all the content) that gets moved. As for plugins, I've used [jQuery Tools](http://jquerytools.org/) a few times

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hkFPB/31/) what you mean?

HTML

```
    <body>
        Content
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="footer_contents">
                    <div class="square selected">1</div>
                    <div class="square">2</div>
                    <div class="square">3</div>
                    <div class="square">4</div>
                    <div class="square">5</div>
                    <div class="square">6</div>
                    <div class="square">7</div>
                    <div class="square">8</div>
                    <div class="square">9</div>
                    <div class="square">10</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

CSS

```
.footer {
    height:50px; 
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}   

.footer_contents {
    height: 50px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
}
```